# Easier way to compute integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the integral of $(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}$ over the rectangle with vertices $(1,2),(2,4),(5,0),(6,2)$. In Cartesian coordinates this translates into

$$\int_{1}^{2}\int_{5/2-x/2}^{2x}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}dydx+\int_{2}^{5}\int_{5/2-x/2}^{5-x/2}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}dydx+\int_{5}^{6}\int_{2x-10}^{5-x/2}(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}dydx$$

which looks rather complicated.

Is there an easier way of computing this integral?

Comment: You could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem for example. Or choose a linear coordinate transformation such that the sides of your rectangle are pairwise parallel to the axes.

Comment: Rotate the frame of reference  $x = u \cos\theta - v\sin \theta,y = u\ \sin\theta + v\cos \theta.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x = u - 2v\\
y = 2u + v\\
dy dx = \|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial u},\frac {\partial x}{\partial v})\times(\frac {\partial y}{\partial u}\frac {\partial y}{\partial v})\|dudv\\
dy dx = 5 du dv\\
u = \frac {2y + x}{5}\\
v = \frac {y - 2x}{5}\\
u(1,2) = 1,v(1,2) = 0\\
u(2,4) = 2,v(1,2) = 0\\
u(5,0) = 1,v(1,2) = -2\\
u(5,0) = 2,v(1,2) = -2\\
x^2 + y^2 = 5(u^2 + v^2)\\
\int_{-2}^0\int_1^2 125(u^2 + v^2)^2 du dv$

I could have used $x = \frac {u-2v}{\sqrt5}, y = \frac {2u+v}{\sqrt5}$ at the top and perhaps saved myself some of the scale distortions.

Had I done that, I would have:

$\int_{-2\sqrt 5}^0\int_{\sqrt5}^{2\sqrt 5} (u^2 + v^2)^2 du dv$